# Make Protractor wait for an alert box?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am writing E2E tests for a log in page. If the log in fails, an alert box pops up informing the user of the invalid user name or password. The log in itself is a call to a web service and the controller is handling the callback. When I use `browser.switchTo().alert();` in Protractor, it happens before the callback finishes. Is there a way I can make Protractor wait for that alert box to pop up?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I solved similar task with the following statement in my Protractor test:

```
browser.wait(function() {
    return browser.switchTo().alert().then(
        function() { return true; }, 
        function() { return false; }
    );
});
```

In general, this code constantly tries to switch to an alert until success (when the alert is opened at last). Some more details:
"browser.wait" waits until called function returns true.
"browser.switchTo().alert()" tries to switch to an opened alert box and either has success, or fails.
Since "browser.switchTo().alert()" returns a promise, then the promise either resolved and the first function runs (returns true), or rejected and the second function runs (returns false).

Comment: Could you explain how this code works, in particular why then() contains what it does?

Comment: @Samuli Kärkkäinen  
Explanation added to the answer. Hope this helps :)

Comment: None of the devs running tests ever saw the alert switchTo fail but 1 in 10 times the CI server did. Your solution saved the day, Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You may use the ExpectedConditions library now, which makes the code more readable:

```
function openAndCloseAlert () {
  var alertButton = $('#alertbutton');
  alertButton.click();

  // wait up to 1000ms for alert to pop up.
  browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent(), 1000); 

  var alertDialog = browser.switchTo().alert();
  expect(alertDialog.getText()).toEqual('Hello');
  alertDialog.accept();
};
```